# How to display data using ngFor without creating a separate div for the input value

Tags: angular

[image]

For invoice form how to display input value for each product object without creating a separate div of each?

ngModel works but since I want to display the selected product price on the input value it is creating the separate div of each product.

```
<div class="uk-column-1-4" >
    <div>
        <select class="uk-select uk-margin-top">
        <option *ngFor="let productDetail of product">{{ productDetail.productName }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
            <input class="uk-input uk-margin-top" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" value="productDetail.qty" />
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let productDetail of product"> 
    <input class="uk-input uk-margin-top" id="price" name="price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.price" /><span>₹</span>
</div>
<div>

</div>
    </div>
```

I want to display the price of the selected product name on the input field itself without generating the separate field.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. Could you elaborate more on *which div* you are talking about? Maybe try even including a stackblitz..

Comment: In the code there is a input field with the name as price, I am using *ngFor for looping on the product object but it is creating the seperate input field for each product selected which I don't want I want to display the selected product price on the same input field without creating new one. How this can done?

Comment: Do you mean like `{{productDetail.price}}` below the `<input>`?

Comment: No on the input field itself.

Comment: Input is used to *accept* data from the user. Why exactly are you using an input tag here?

Comment: So that user can edit the price if he wants to. I have added output picture on the question section.

Comment: As long as you are using a `<input>` within the `*ngFor`, it will create *multiple* input tags. Maybe you need to use a `*ngIf` in your input that way just one input tag with the selected criteria will be shown?

Comment: I want to display the selected product name price on the input field. According to the  list of product name selected the appropriate price should be displayed so what selection criteria can be applied here?

Comment: In the code, the "product" is a collection of "productDetails". But on the screen and in your text, you use the word "product" for what is actually a productDetail. This is confusing. If I am right, please replace `product` by `productList` and `productDetail` by `product`, or alternatively, use the word product detail instead of product in your regular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ngModel` on the `select` which will get you the selected product and then make a function to change the index(`j`) of the selected product, which can be set to bind the input field with that selected product.

```html
<div class="uk-column-1-4" >
    <div>
        <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" name="selectedOption" class="uk-select uk-margin-top">
        <option *ngFor="let productDetail of product; let i = index" [value]="i">{{ productDetail.productName }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
            <input class="uk-input uk-margin-top" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" value="productDetail.qty" />
    </div>
    
    <input class="uk-input uk-margin-top" id="price" name="price" type="number" [(ngModel)]=" [(ngModel)]="product.length==0?tempPrice:product[j]['price']" /><span>₹</span>

<div>

</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsduc4)

The error was that when `product` array is empty, the `product[j]` i.e `product[0]` was undefined and I solved it by creating a temp variable(`tempPrice`) for binding the input when the `product` is empty.

Hope this helps :)
comment for further assistance.

Comment: Do you get the error before you select an option or after?

Comment: before. Actually the products I am adding the list is not displaying after adding this code.

Comment: Mr-K10's answer is a hint, not a complete solution. If you understand the approach, you should be able to write the rest of the code yourself. Make sure you initialize j properly and that changeTheIndex assigns i to j.

Comment: The index `i` used for function in `onModelChange` was out of scope, so changed the code, Now check it out.
`[(ngModel)]="product[j].price"` this may also produce some errors, you may 
 have to check it as well or you can provide the code(stackblitz link) to make the required changes.

Comment: What should I write in onChange function please help me I have provided the code in stackblitz link. Thank you :)

Comment: How this same can be done in case of reactive forms?

Comment: This is rather easy when it comes to reactive forms, try reading the official documentation.